# dplyr summary by group using cumulative approach

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame like this

```
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                  x = 1:16,
                  y = 16:1)

library(dplyr)
```

I want to do following operation for each `id`

```
for id 1, do mean(x)/mean(y), 
for id 2, do mean(x)/mean(y) where x and y includes values from id 1 and 2 
for id 3, do mean(x)/mean(y) where x and y includes values from id 1, 2 and 3 
for id 4, do mean(x)/mean(y) where x and y includes values from id 1, 2, 3 and 4
```

I did a traditional for loop to do this

```
temp.vec <- list()
for(l in sort(unique(dat$id))){
  
  temp.vec[[l]] <- dat %>% 
                   dplyr::filter(id <= l) %>%
                   dplyr::summarise(value = mean(x)/mean(y)) 
  print(l)
}

result <- rbindlist(temp.vec)
result 
value
1: 0.1724138
2: 0.3600000
3: 0.6190476
4: 1.0000000
```

Can I do this using dplyr?

Comment: There is a `dplyr::cummean` function for cumulative mean. If your data is sorted by `id` that should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion. The function does not give me what I am looking for which is a a summary instead of a running mean

Comment: What is your desired result? Use `set.seed()` so we can replicate your sample data. And may be make it smaller so you can supply show the exact output you desire. I'm not sure what the "flag" has to do with anything. You seem to know what to do for one value so I'm not sure why you are including the part you already know how to do. It just seems to be making things more difficult to understand.

Comment: Okay. let me please edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean_x = mean(x), mean_y = mean(y)) %>%
  mutate(result = cumsum(mean_x) / cumsum(mean_y)) %>%
  pluck("result")
```